# Why is my while loop still running even when the condition is false?

Tags: java, while-loop, infinite-loop

I want to create a quiz that gives an error message that the answer is invalid if the users input (the answer variable) does not equal "A", "B", "C", "D", or "E" and then asks the question again for a new input. Even when answer DOES equal "A", "B", "C", "D", or "E", the while loop still runs and I am having trouble figuring out why. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Quiz {
    static String ask(String Question) {
        String answer = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(Question);
        answer = answer.toUpperCase();
        while (!answer.equals("A") || !answer.equals("B") || !answer.equals("C") || 
!answer.equals("D") || !answer.equals("E")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Invalid answer. Please enter A, B, C, D, or E.");
            Quiz.ask(Question);
        }
    return answer;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String question = "What is a user defined blueprint from which objects are created in Java?\n";
    question += "A. Method\n";
    question += "B. Variable\n";
    question += "C. Class\n";
    question += "D. Loop\n";
    question += "E. Array";
    Quiz.ask(question);
    }
}
```

Comment: The `answer` cannot be at the same time `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, and `E`. Be careful when you combine `OR` and logical negation. Side note: your `ask` executions stack up unnecessarily (rather use a *do-while* loop and have `JOptionPane.showInputDialog(Question)` in the loop instead of calling `Quiz.ask(Question)` recursively.

Comment: You probably want your condition to be `while(!answer.equals("A") && !answer.equals("B") && !answer.equals("C") && 
!answer.equals("D") && !answer.equals("E"))` or `while(!(answer.equals("A") || answer.equals("B") || answer.equals("C") || 
answer.equals("D") || answer.equals("E")))`

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply. I do not want the answer to be all of them at the same time though. I want to make it so that if it is not any of the 5 valid answers ("A", "B", "C", "D" or "E"), I get an invalid error. The first suggestion works if I give a valid answer the first time, BUT if I first input an invalid answer, I want the loop to then stop if I input a valid answer but in that case it still gives me an invalid error repeatedly.

Comment: Also, if by any chance I clarified what I was looking for in that I do NOT want answer to be all 5 of them and just one of them, do you have another suggestion? Thank you again.

Comment: Don't call `Quiz.ask(Question)` recursively. Use a **do-while** loop

Comment: Hi. How would I do that successfully? Could you please show me? I am struggling to figure that out. Thank you.

Comment: Like what would the new continuation condition be? It looks like I would have to put those conditions in an if statement if  did a do-while

Answer (score 2):

Not A or Not B or Not C or Not D or Not E is logically equivalent to A and B and C and D and E.  (DeMorgans Law)  You want Not A and Not B and Not C and Not D and Not C

Comment: Got it.. But yes, that is what I want. I do not want answer to be equal to any of those when the loop runs. But when answer equals one of the 5, the loop should be false in that case yet it still runs. Thank you!

Comment: In another comment I see that you say this condition now works if initial entry is correct it works but initial invalid won't break. Are you testing with lower case letters? I see that your using .toUpperCase() and evaluating uppercase in loop. Try using .equalsIgnoreCase() instead of .toUpperCase() and evaluating case.

Comment: Hi Matthew. Thank you for your suggestion, but this is actually an assignment and I have to evaluate based on the uppercase so I had to use that method so it evaluates that way even if I input a lowercase letter.

Answer (score 2):

You have two problems.

First, your condition is incorrect. If you want to check that the answer is any of the allowed values, then your condition should be either of:

```
!answer.equals("A") && !answer.equals("B") 
    && !answer.equals("C") && !answer.equals("D")
    && !answer.equals("E")
```

and

```
!(answer.equals("A") || answer.equals("B") 
    || answer.equals("C") || answer.equals("D")
    || answer.equals("E"))
```

See [Matthew's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60218835/5761558) for an explanation.

Second, you're calling `Quiz.ask(Question)` recursively, which makes your loop continue running on invalid answers, even if the user supplies a correct answer in a subsequent call (please read on and understand how recursive calls work - particularly how local variables are managed). 
A fix for this would be a do-while loop (there are other ways to do it), as in:

```
String answer;
boolean invalid = false;
do {
    if(invalid) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                "Invalid answer. Please enter A, B, C, D, or E.");
    }

    answer = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(Question);
    answer = answer.toUpperCase();
    invalid = !(answer.equals("A") || answer.equals("B") 
               || answer.equals("C") || answer.equals("D")
               || answer.equals("E"));
} while (invalid);
    return answer;
```

Comment: Thank you! So where would I place the invalid statement?

Comment: I would not want it to output before the user inputs anything

Comment: Okay, that worked. Thank you very much. I appreciate all your help.

Answer (score 0):

- The **"[While Loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html)"** continues as long as the condition is evaluated as true.
- **"||" ([OR logical operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html))** only return false if all statements are false, ex.:
  false || false = false

In your code, if the user chooses B, for example, the first evaluation `!answer.equals("A")` break what you want, returning **true** and ignoring the other statements.

Change your "while loop" to evaluate correctly your condition according you want (keep asking until the answer is different from "A" or "B" or "C" or "D" or "E"). So, express exactly that:

```
while ( !( answer.equals("A") || answer.equals("B") || answer.equals("C") || answer.equals("D") || answer.equals("E") ) ){
   ...
}
```

**Note the "!" (NOT logical operator)** and the use of **parentheses**, this is essential for it to work.